# Create every 2 hour Timer and display message box

Tags: timer, notifications, vb6

I'm trying to create a program that will alarm every 2 hours and a message box will be display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Timer control to do this but you will not be able to directly set the Interval to 7200000. You could set your Interval to 60000 (and set Enabled property to `True`) and have a variable that counts the minutes that have gone by:

```
Dim iMinutesElapsed As Integer

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    iMinutesElapsed = iMinutesElapsed + 1
    If iMinutesElapsed = 120 Then
        DoAlarm
        iMinutesElapsed = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DoAlarm()
    MsgBox "2 hours have gone by."
End Sub
```

A better approach is to store a variable with the value of the [Timer function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function) and check how long it's been since you called `Start`. In this approach, set  Timer1's Interval to 1000 and Enabled to False, the `Start` method will enable Timer1 for you:

```
Dim sngStart As Single

Public Sub Start()
    sngStart = Timer
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Dim sngElapsedTime As Single

    sngElapsedTime = Timer - sngStart
    If sngElapsedTime < 0 Then
        ' Clock passed midnight
        sngElapsedTime = (86400 - sngStart) + Timer
    End If

    If sngElapsedTime > 7200 Then ' counting seconds with this code
        sngStart = Timer ' Restart
        DoAlarm
    End If

End Sub
```

Finally, a solution that will be triggered every odd hour on minute 30 as described in the comments:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    If Hour(Now) Mod 2 = 1 And Minute(Now) = 30 Then
        DoAlarm
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What if i set time for example 7:30 , 9:30 ,11:30

Comment: That's simple too, you can just check if `Hour(Now) Mod 2 = 1 And Minute(Now) = 30`, using Interval of 60000 on your Timer

Comment: what i mean is I set 7:30AM , 9:30AM ,11:30AM,1:30PM, 3:30PM ,5:30PM,7:30PM, 9:30PM ,11:30PM,1:30AM, 3:30AM ,5:30AM then in every 2hrs it will display a message box

Comment: The code in my last comment will do exactly that. It checks if the hour is an odd number and minutes are 30. You can run this in the `Timer1_Timer` event.

Comment: Thank you bro, The first code is working , I'm working on the last comment now

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to set a module-level variable to the current time + two hours (`Now + (2.0 / 24.0)`), then have the Timer interrupt check to see if the current time is greater than this stored value.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Task Scheduler to run a VBScript that displays your message box. You simply have to create a Task with a Trigger that repeats every 2 hours, indefinitely.

The VBScript can display the time:

```
MsgBox "It's now " & FormatDateTime(Now, vbShortTime)
```